# Is LUKS Anti-Forensic information splitter (AFsplit) indistinguishable from random data?

Tags: implementation, randomness, deniable-encryption

I want to know if **[`AFsplit`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~lenz/luks/AfSplitter.txt)**`(random_data_input, stripes, digestmod=sha)` output is indistinguishable from random data.

The attacker only has access to `AFsplit` output data.

**EDIT:** This question is too vague as the answer depends on the randomness hypothesis taken about `random_input_data`. Take care of it reading the proposed answers.

The purpose is to use this function in a deniable encryption implementation.

*About AFsplit: AFsplit provides a security against forensic attacks on disk bad blocks. AFsplit splits data among several disk blocks so that if a block is put in reserved "bad block" area, it doesn't contain a complete sensitive information (particularly, a revoked key slot). LUKS uses AFsplit to store the key slots.*

*Note: I'm not speaking of LUKS itself that is, of course, a plain header. I just want to focus on this particular function.*

Below is AFsplit Python implementation:

```
import sha, string, math, struct
from Crypto.Util.randpool import RandomPool
from Crypto.Cipher import XOR
def _xor(a, b):
    """Internal function to performs XOR on two strings a and b"""

    xor = XOR.new(a)
    return xor.encrypt(b)

def _diffuse(block, size, digest):
    """Internal function to diffuse information inside a buffer"""

    # Compute the number of full blocks, and the size of the leftover block
    full_blocks = int(math.floor(float(len(block)) / float(digest.digest_size)))
    padding = len(block) % digest.digest_size

    # hash the full blocks
    ret = ""
    for i in range(0, full_blocks):

        hash = digest.new()
        hash.update(struct.pack(">I", i))
        hash.update(block[i*digest.digest_size:(i+1)*digest.digest_size])
        ret += hash.digest()

    # Hash the remaining data
    if padding > 0:
        hash = digest.new()
        hash.update(struct.pack(">I", full_blocks))
        hash.update(block[full_blocks * digest.digest_size:])
        ret += hash.digest()[:padding]

    return ret

def AFSplit(data, stripes, digestmod=sha):
    """AF-Split data using digestmod.  Returned data size will be len(data) * stripes"""

    blockSize = len(data)

    rand = RandomPool()

    bufblock = "\x00" * blockSize

    ret = ""
    for i in range(0, stripes-1):

        # Get some random data
        rand.randomize()
        rand.stir()
        r = rand.get_bytes(blockSize)
        if rand.entropy < 0:
            print "Warning: RandomPool entropy dropped below 0"

        ret += r
        bufblock = _xor(r, bufblock)
        bufblock = _diffuse(bufblock, blockSize, digestmod)
        rand.add_event(bufblock)

    ret += _xor(bufblock, data)
    return ret
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**EDIT to be more clear regarding hypothesis**

I was too lazy to do the code analysis but it had to be done to provide an objective answer. This function mechanism is indeed poorly known.

The **function itself doesn't** provide an output indistinguishable from random data.

However, if and only if these **3 conditions are met**, the output **is** indistinguishable from random data:

- The implementation uses a secured RNG (random-number generator). Note that Python [Crypto.Util.randpool is deprecated](https://lists.dlitz.net/pipermail/pycrypto/2008q3/000000.html)!
- AFSplit **input data is indistinguishable from random data**.
- The attacker has only access to AFsplit output data

Note that it is unecessary that AFSplit input digest (hashing algorithm) provides an output indistinguishable from random data. The hashing algorithm choice adds nothing to the randomness.

AFsplit is commonly used (by LUKS) to split a randomly-generated key, that's why the second condition is often met and was somehow implied in the question by using `random_data_input` variable name.

### Demonstration

Human readable, not Python, `.` means concatenate, `⊕` means XOR, `NULL` means the NULL character, `[:3]` means the first 3 characters:

`AFSplit("D₁D₂D₃", 2, sha256)` = `"R₁R₂R₃R₄R₅R₆".("S₄S₅S₆"⊕"D₁D₂D₃")`

Where:

- `"D₁D₂D₃"` is the chosen input sequence of 3 characters (example key).
- `2` is the chosen number of stripes (example).
- `"R₁R₂R₃R₄R₅R₆"` is a sequence of 6 random characters generated by the RNG
- `"S₁S₂S₃"` = `_diffuse("R₁R₂R₃", 3, sha256)` = `sha256(NULL."R₁R₂R₃")[:3]`. This is the result of the 1st _diffuse iteration.
- `"S₄S₅S₆"` = `_diffuse("R₄R₅R₆"⊕"S₁S₂S₃", 3, sha256) = sha256(NULL."R₄⊕S₁"."R₅⊕S₂"."R₆⊕S₃")[:3]`. This is the result of the 2nd _diffuse iteration.

*Note that AFSplit `_diffuse` function behaves a bit differently when len(data) >= digest.digest_size, by hashing the input in chunks. This is not taken into account in this example. The conclusion is the same anyway.*

In more comprehensible terms, AFsplit output contains:

- A bunch of **leading stripes** `"R₁R₂R₃R₄R₅R₆"` containing random data generated by the PRNG. The leading stripes length = `stripes` x length(`random_data_input`).
- The **last stripe** `("S₄S₅S₆"⊕"D₁D₂D₃")`. Its length is equal to length(`random_data_input`). This last stripe is a XOR between:

  1. A hash combination `"S₄S₅S₆"` of the randomly-generated leading stripes
  2. The input data `"D₁D₂D₃"`

So if some (but not all) stripes are seized in a disk bad block, this disk-seized stripes won't be sufficient to apply the opposite `AFmerge` function to reconstitute the leading stripes hash combination, in order to de-XOR `random_input_data`. That's the very purpose of `AFsplit`/`AFmerge`: you need ALL `AFsplit` output data to apply `AFmerge` and reconstitute `random_input_data`.

To come back to the question:

- The leading stripes are generated by the PRNG, so they are as much random as what the PRNG provides.
- Regarding the last stripe `"S₄S₅S₆"⊕"D₁D₂D₃"`:

  1. The hash combinaton `"S₄S₅S₆"` can be reconsituted from the known output leading stripes `"R₁R₂R₃R₄R₅R₆"`, so the hashing adds no entropy/randomness to this last stripe.
  2. The `random_input_data` `"D₁D₂D₃"` entropy/randomness is maximal: By hypothesis, `random_input_data` is indistinguishable from random data.
  3. The resulting XORing `⊕` entropy is equal to the entropy of `"D₁D₂D₃"`, so the result is indistinguishable from user data. See: [Mixing Entropy Sources by XOR?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17658/mixing-entropy-sources-by-xor)

So the answer is yes, if and only if the 3 conditions above are met.

Comment: [The accepted A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12839/12164) posted to [the Q you linked to](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12822/are-the-sha-family-hash-outputs-practically-random) actually contradicts the statements you base your answer on. Quote: *“… the output of hashing a truly random stream is a stream which is bias. This bias will be very small indeed, but it will be there. **So the answer to that specific question is no.**”* (emphasis mine). It goes on explaining such a bias makes it distinguishable from random data. I do not see how that Q&A fits your statements here.

Comment: Also, the Q&A you linked to exclusively mentions the SHA-2 family (SHA256 and SHA-512). The linked Q&A does not mention anything about SHA-1 as used within LUKS (as a diffusion function for `AFSplitting`). Note that  SHA-1 has a somewhat different algorithm design compared to the SHA-2 family, and that SHA-1 has practically been broken using collision attacks – undermining it's cryptographic security claims in several aspects. Therefore, the SHA-2 related Q&A you linked to can/should not be treated as a foundation for any derivative claims about SHA-1. That's like comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Even if the the digest algorithm had an important biais that would allow a practical attack, this hash is XORed with the input data that is indistinguishable from random data (question pre-requisite), making it  indistinguishable from random data. This is mathematical: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17658/mixing-entropy-sources-by-xor

Comment: Edited the question to change digest algorithm output randomness from recommended to useless. We can totally reconstitue S₄S₅S₆ from the output R₁R₂R₃R₄R₅R₆, whatever the algorithm choice. The algorithm does not hash the user input data.

Comment: Your answer seems to be contradictory.  In one sentence you say knowing the random string will "de xor" the user data, but in a following sentence you claim this same random string does not provide any useful information about the data.  Am I reading your statements correctly?  In terms of the logic of your argument, you assume your conclusion to support your argument - this is a fallacy of logic.

Comment: I agree the statement "not knowing random_input_data" can be confusing. I will replaced it by "the attacker only has access to AFsplit output data". Let me explain. From `AFsplit` output data, the attacker can reconstitute `AFsplit` `random_input_data` by applying `AFmerge`. However, that doesn't prove in any way that `random_input_data` data was `AFsplit`ed. However, if the attacker was expecting, by other means (eg. a backup of `random_input_data`), to find exactly `random_input_data`, then he can prove that it was `AFsplit`ed. That's what I meant when I say "not knowing random_input_data".

Answer (score 4):

> Is LUKS Anti-Forensic information splitter (AFsplit) indistinguishable from random data?

No.

AFSplitting is merely meant to provide [diffusion](/questions/tagged/diffusion), not cryptographically secure randomness.

When you check the LUKS On-Disk Format Specification ([eg PDF of v1.1.1](http://tomb.dyne.org/Luks_on_disk_format.pdf)) you'll notice it states

> LUKS uses anti-forensic information splitting as specified in [Fru05b]. The underlaying **diffusion** function shall be SHA1 for the reference implementation, but can be changed exactly as described in the remarks above.

Even though the (broken due collision attacks) SHA-1 function is used as a diffusion function in the reference implementation, that doesn't mean the AFSplitting function does provide any more than that – diffusion.

While it definitely has a (let's just call it) random character, you should not generally rely on it to provide cryptographically secure randomness indistinguishable from random data. That's not what AFSplitting (by itself) is intended to provide. While diffusion surely adds to randomness, there's a big difference between “diffusion” and “cryptographically secure randomness indistinguishable from random data”. Both are hardly exchangeable terms.

---

And I'm not yet considdering practical breaks against SHA-1 which also *might* or *might not* render the answer into a clear “no”… but [that's another question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/50839/12164).

---

### EDIT

To clarify this a bit more indeep, trying to clear up some confusion in the comments by the asker.

Let's remember the question asked

> I want to know if `AFsplit(random_data_input, stripes, digestmod=sha)` output is indistinguishable from random data, not knowing random_data_input.

and

> … I just want to focus on this particular function.

The question didn't ask if PBKDF2 is indistinguishable from random data and the question did not assume input to AFSplit to be indistinguishable from random data either.

Therefore, when merely focussing on the AFSplit functionality (as the question asks), one can and has to cryptanalytically assume distinguishable data inputs too. Otherwise, the input to AFSplit would have needed to be defined as “exclusively data indistinguishable from random data”, but the question doesn't limit the input to such indistinguishable data when asking what AFSplitting outputs.

In LUKS the user password is entered and processed by PBKDF2 (which provides the randomness which *should* be indistinguishable from random data.  The master key is then splitted by the AFsplitter into a number of stripes… via diffusion (using SHA-1 or an alternative replacement).

So, any data indistinguishable from random data needs to be produced outside the AFSplit function. If you'ld feed AFSplit distinguishable data, AFSplit won't magically turn the data you feed it into data indistinguishable from random data; it merely diffuses what you feed it. That's all you get when keeping the focus on this particular function (and the main reason for **no** as an answer). How the input to AFSplit should be produced in a LUKS implementation is another story, and goes well beyond the AFSplit function (which is merely a diffusion-providing piece of the LUKS cake) and therefore well beyond what was being asked – which was to focus on this particular function.

Comment: This rationale is flawed. First, all AFsplit stripes except the last stripe are just random characters generated by the PRNG so they have a much entropy/randomness as what the PRNG provides. Second, the last AFsplit stripe is a XOR between (1) a hash combination of the  resulting leading stripes (2) the input data. This hash (1) adds absolutely no entropy/randomness as it can be reconstituted by the attacker from the AFsplit result leading stripes. So the last stripe entropy/randomness is equal to the input data entropy/randomness (2) **whatever the hashing agorithm choice**.

Comment: @KrisWebDev Edited A which should clarify some things. Somehow we both seem to agree on 99% of what AFSplit does, yet somehow you end up with a different conclusion… even though your comment confirms what I wrote. I can only guess you're confusing PBKDF2 randomness to be part of AFSplit. It isn't. It's what is being fed as input. But the Q didn't limit inputs in any way. You wrote `not knowing random_data_input`, so one has to assume `random_data_input` can also be non-random and cryptanalytically check AFSplit output. I hope my edit clarifies the point you're missing in your "yes" conclusion.

Comment: OK, we were not on the same hypothesis. The name `random_data_input` implied input data was indistinguishable from user data, I've made it more clear. If it is not random then AFsplit output isn't and that's what you demonstrate. AFsplit is commonly used (by LUKS) to split a randomly-generated key, hence this hypothesis on random input data.

Answer (score -2):

This technique allows to spread some small data all over the disk sector. The sector is partitioned in several random stripes and you need all of them to get the data. 
So, yes, the sector has a random aspect.