# Forward Patterns in SHA 256

Tags: sha-256

Would it be possible to find a correlation between the inputs of SHA 256 and it's outputs? More specifically, by using deep learning, would there exist a correlation between the inputs of an SHA 256 algorithm and it's expected output?

For example, given that A, B, C and D output a Has with certain characteristics, and given that we have a very big sample of data that has a combination of inputs and their outputs (labeled based on whether the output FITS into the characteristics or not), could a pattern be found so that in the future we could know which combination of inputs would give us an output that complies with said characteristics?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're effectively asking about whether it's possible to find a differential cryptanalysis attack that works on a non-reduced-round version. Machine learning isn't magic, and isn't really relevant to this field, so it somewhat confuses the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of hash functions is commonly indistinguishable from random (randomness of the output is not a direct requirement for secure hash functions); this is certainly the case for SHA-256. So trying to find any correlation between inputs should be impossible - if there is some kind of pattern on different inputs it was created by chance.

If you would find such a correlation then the hash function would be considered broken. Deep learning should therefore be considered another way of attacking the hash using machine learning, [as the comment from SAI Peregrinus](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54764/forward-patterns-in-sha-256#comment121207_54764) indicates.

An important note in this case is that Merkle Damgard constructions such as SHA-256 [are susceptible to length extension attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51084/1172), which means that SHA-256 is not a random oracle. That won't help you finding a pattern in separate input messages so I don't think it should influence this answer.

Comment: Hi Marteen, thanks for your answer. It was very informative. So, in order to summarize my understanding after reading your answer, it would be impossible to correlate inputs of SHA-256 with their outputs because the output, even though it's deterministic, behaves randomly? (As in, it's not possible to predict what the output of a HASH function would be unless running it). Sorry if my questions are too elemental, i'm just starting to learn a bit about cryptography. Thanks! PS: When i mean finding a pattern, it's between a set of inputs and their outputs.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. The first paragraph leaves some doubt about it, I'll revisit the answer later.

Comment: (it is of course pseudo random, it depends on the input - but there are no ways other than to go through the hash function in some form or other to obtain the result)